# What's the difference between "incoherence" and "inconsistency"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I find those two words a little confusing, so what are some contexts in which it's appropriate to use the word "incoherence/incoherent" rather than "inconsistency/inconsistent"?

Also, can the word "incoherence" be used like this "The Incoherence of X" to imply X not having a solid logical ground?

Comment: A person who's "incoherent" can't speak an intelligible sentence.  A person who is "inconsistent" is a politician.

Comment: If something is incoherent it makes no sense- it is a data stream that cannot be deciphered. If it's inconsistent the data stream can be deciphered but the data within it is erratic.

Comment: @Jim rather the data within it is contradictory.

Comment: @deadrat- Well, contradictory data is one kind of inconsistency, but I would say that if the data represented a set of repeated measurements and instead of having a very small standard deviation, they varied greatly from measurement to measurement that would be inconsistent without being out-n-out contradictory. I suppose one could argue that if I measured the same distance twice and got 10'4" the first time and 8'7" the second time that might be more than just inconsistent, that would be contradictory.

Comment: The two words are quite synonyms. However, incoherence is related to a lack of logic and inconsistency refers to some specific contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words do have somewhat overlapping meanings, and a quick dictionary search shows that the definitions tend to reference each other.  But they tend to refer to different things and the connotations depend on context.

In general, *inconsistent* tends to refer to clear contradiction (often a specific contradiction) on some level, while *incoherent* can be a more general state of confusion.

For example, if measurements are *inconsistent*, that means some explicitly disagree with others (e.g., some are high, others are low).  If measurements are *incoherent*, there is generally a greater level of confusion that does not permit a clear interpretation (e.g., the meter can't be read clearly to even determine the measurements).

When referring to logical proofs or philosophical systems, the implication is similar.  A system which is logically *inconsistent* may not work in all cases, but the failure is likely to be a very specific point of contradiction.  A system which is logically *incoherent* has more fundamental flaws which would perhaps cause the entire system to fall apart.  Philosophers do, however, sometimes use the word *incoherent* to refer to a system with specific contradictions of logic (i.e., inconsistencies).  Basically, I'd say *inconsistent* can refer to a specific flaw (an *inconsistency*), while there's no such thing as a single *incoherency* -- the system either passes and is *coherent* or fails completely and is *incoherent*.

Comment: Actually, a system that is logically inconsistent cannot work **at all**. An inconsistency cannot be contained, because, as a matter of logic, anything can be derived from a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

The words are closely related. In general, they both say that "it is hard to make sense" of something. The dictionaries give similar explanations, and in real use, the words are often used interchangeably. I guess, this is not just due to their close semantic proximity, but also due to their lexicologic similarities: They both start with the negation prefix "in-", followed by a syllable indicating a connection ("co-" or "con-"). That is why they are often confused, making the difference blurry. Just from inspecting spoken language, one could make a case and argue that there is no *pragmatic* difference in most cases.

However, besides this loose meaning, the words also have a stricter meaning, and it is possible to give a clear *analytic* distinction, a clear definition of the words. (This does not mean, that it would always be easy to apply this definition to real-world sentences.) If you want to be more precise, this is the difference:

A statement is *inconsistent* if it contains a logical contradiction, be it implied or explicit. This is how the term *inconsistent* is used in logic and philosophy.<sup>[1]</sup>An example is for an explicit contradiction is:

> It is raining but it is not raining.

The second main clause is a clear logical contradiction to the first main clause.

An example for an implied contradiction is:

> I was not able to pick up my million lottery win, because it would have required showing up on a Tuesday at 7pm. But Tuesday evenings I would always go playing snooker. So by no means I was able to make it.

(The implied contradiction here is technically based on the additional premise that picking up a million should be more important to you than keeping up the routine of a hobby like billiards. But that premise is so weak, that most people would see a contradiction implied in the statement.)

*Coherence* denotes a "state of being connected" (also see *cohesion*). A statement is *incoherent*, if semantic relations of parts of speech are vague, or if some references which are crucial for understanding remain unresolved. This is how the word is used in text linguistics and theory of linguistic style.<sup>[2], [3]</sup> An example is:

> Susi and her daughters like green. But he was not there.

Here, the second sentence has some unresolved references. "But" would indicate a logical relation of the second sentence to the first. But it is totally left open, what this relation would be. This is a break of coherence, it is incoherent. Also the referent "he" in the second sentence is incoherent. The first sentence references only persons which are being identified as female. It is not clear, to whom "he" is referring. This is a another lack of coherence. In a similar fashion, it is unclear, what "there" is referring to.

Another example for an incoherent statement is:

> First, I wash my hair. Second, I go shopping. And fourth, I go to the gym.

This is obviously raising a question - *What do you do third?*. Skipping this is breaking coherence.

As you can see, the incoherent statements are in no means logically contradictive, they are not *inconsistent* in the stricter meaning of the word.

From a logical perspective, one could say that incoherent statements are *underspecified* - they contain "too little" information to be understood. Adding information might resolve the issue. On the other hand, inconsistent statements are *overspecified* - they contain "too much" information to make sense. Leaving something out might make the statement consistent.

References:

[1] https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Consistency
[2] https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Coherence_(linguistics)
[3] https://www.linguistik.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg72/PDF/MSF_Publikation/Schwarz_2001b.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, a good answer ... but the stipulative definitions do need references.

Comment: Is it possible for something to be inconsistent and not be incoherent? The answer leaves that unclear.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach For me? Read the recommendations about good answers at the site's Help Center. ELU is self-policing, but according to laid-down regulations etc.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that, according to your answer, inconsistency is a semantic notion, while incoherence is a pragmatic notion?

Answer (score 2):

### A [brief] etymological note:

"**Consist**" comes from words that mean *to **stay** or **stand** together*, from the PIE root "sta", whose "st" sound you can hear if you say the words *consist, state, stay, stand, Pakistan, ecstasy*, among others, which you can explore at the following etymonline link if you care to.

> **consist (v.)**
>
> 1520s, "to be, exist in a permanent state as a body composed of
> parts," from French *consister* (14c.) or directly from Latin consistere "to stand firm, take a standing position, stop, halt," from assimilated form of *com* "with, together" (see con-) + *sistere* "to place," causative of *stare* "to stand, be standing" (from PIE root ***sta-** "to stand, make or be firm"). ([etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=consist))

"**Cohere**" comes from words meaning *to **adhere** together*, as with glue or some other agent that resists separation.

> **coherent (adj.)**
>
> 1550s, "harmonious;" 1570s, "sticking together," also "connected, consistent" (of speech, thought, etc.), from French *cohérent* (16c.), from Latin *cohaerentem* (nominative *cohaerens*), present participle of *cohaerere* "cohere," from assimilated form of *com* "together" (see co-) + *haerere* "to adhere, stick" (see hesitation). ([etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=cohere))

At the risk of getting scolded for comission of the etymological fallacy, I cannot keep from commenting that things can technically be said to "stand" together without being "stuck" together.

Comment: But then we talk of being stuck in a traffic jam.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, we do; although the verb "to stick" in this sense originally meant "to be pierced through", and that is not the case in a traffic jam. In this regard, "I am coherent with a traffic jam" is how the phrase Should Have (tm) evolved, since the _-here_ root, according to etymonline, "is said by Watkins to be from PIE root *ghais- "to adhere, hesitate" (source also of Lithuanian gaišti "to delay, tarry, be slow"), but some linguists reject the proposed connection; de Vaan offers no etymology." I think that adhesives are relatively recent tech; nails have been around much longer.

Comment: I'm waiting for Jonathan Scholbach to add references; his answer seems very useful. But as usual, [narrow definition] + [narrow definition] will = argument. _A hurricane, but not a hurricane_.

Comment: Note that the root for "-here" is one of those that underwent rhotacism in early Latin, producing "-hesion" as a nominalization and "-hesive" as an adjectivalization.

Answer (score 1):

Incoherent implies that something is unintelligible - something that can not be understood, often due to confusion. It is mainly used to describe something said or written, as words can often be confusing or misunderstood.
*The drunk professor's incoherent ramblings were the first signs of his worsening condition.*

Inconsistent describes something that does not follow a particular pattern. *I am always late for work because the bus schedule is inconsistent.*